# Load Keycloak App inside iframe or similar thing to work inside web page

Tags: angular, iframe, keycloak, keycloak-services

I want to load KeyCloak inside a part of web Page (App component) using Angular & to do some authentication of User. I tried using `<iframe>` but its not loading the keycloak screen.

```
<iframe id="keycloak-iframe" src="https://your-keycloak-domain/auth/realms/your-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=your-client-id&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://your-application-domain/callback" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But its not loading inside iframe. I want like similar to the screen shot attached.[image]

Comment: Getting error in console 
Refused to frame 'http://localhost:8080/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

Added this configuration in Keycloak configuration: 
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' http://localhost:8080/